# Writing DAX in calculated field

Tags: powerbi, powerpivot

I have 2 tables:

A. Customer, dimension table, with customer key as primary key.
Key fields include:

- Customer key,
- 1stPurchaseDate (Date)

B. Sales,  fact table, with customer key as foreign key.
Key fields include:

- Sales order date (Date),
- Customer key

I want to create a DAX to know the count of sales order per 1st purchase month (like Jul 2017), with sales(customer key) = customer (customer key), sales order date within 60 days since first purchase.

I can create it in calculated column in below:

```
=CALCULATE(COUNT(Sales[ProductKey]),FILTER(Sales,Sales[OrderDate]>Customers[DateFirstPurchase] && Sales[OrderDate] - Customers[DateFirstPurchase] <=60 && Sales[CustomerKey] = Customers[CustomerKey]))
```

But how can I do it in DAX (calculated field)?

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

First, create a relationship in your model (if you use PowerPivot see an article from this site:)

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/relationships-between-tables-in-a-data-model-533dc2b6-9288-4363-9538-8ea6e469112b

Second, modify your statement and use SELECTEDVALUE

```
CALCULATE(COUNT(Sales[ProductKey]),FILTER(Sales, SELECTEDVALUE(Sales[OrderDate])>Customers[DateFirstPurchase] &&  SELECTEDVALUE(Sales[OrderDate]) <= (Customers[DateFirstPurchase] + 60) ) )
```

Comment: Thanks.
I can't find selectedvalue in my version so used values. I create below measures :

Comment: Purchasewithin90days%:=
var firstpurchase = LOOKUPVALUE(Customers[DateFirstPurchase],Customers[CustomerKey],Sales[CustomerKey])
var returncustomer90 = CALCULATE(COUNT(Sales[SalesOrderNumber]),FILTER(Sales,VALUES(Sales[OrderDate])>firstpurchase && VALUE(Sales[OrderDate])-firstpurchase<=90 && VALUES(Sales[CustomerKey]) = [CustomerKey]))

return 
DIVIDE(returncustomer90,COUNT(Sales[SalesOrderNumber]))

No error after create it but error pops up when place the measure in pivot table. [mdx script (8,65) error, it claims measure create multiple values instead of one.